# Can't get Antlr4 parser to follow order of operations with implicit multiplication

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I'm new to ANTLR and I'm attempting to generate a relatively simply parser for a calculator application, using ANTLR4 and C#. Here is my grammar file.

```
parser grammar CalculatorExpressionParser;

options{
language = CSharp2;
}

expr:  FUNC expr? (COMMA expr)* RIGHTPAREN               #CallFunction
    |  LEFTPAREN expr RIGHTPAREN                         #Parens
    |  expr POW<assoc=right> expr                        #Pow
    |  expr op=(MULTIPLY | DIVIDE)? expr                 #MultDivide
    |  expr op=(ADD | SUBTRACT) expr                     #AddSubtract
    |  SUBTRACT expr                                     #Negative
    |  NUMBER                                            #Number
    ;
```

I wrote a custom lexer to generate the tokens in order to support implicit multiplication and conversion of variables to their numerical equivalent before parsing.

But upon input I get the following results.

```
2+6/3 => 4 (correct)
6/3+2 => 1.2 (should be 4)
6/(3+2) => 4 (also correct)

1+2*3 => 7 (correct)
2*3+1 => 8 (should be 7 too)
(2*3)+1 => 7 (correct)
```

Note that I tried turning off the error recovery capabilities and setting it to report all ambiguity errors and I don't appear to be getting any.

Anyways, if I change the grammar to the following by removing the ? after the division/multiplication operator, then it appears to work great, except implicit multiplication is no longer supported.

```
parser grammar CalculatorExpressionParser;

options{
language = CSharp2;
}

expr:  FUNC expr? (COMMA expr)* RIGHTPAREN               #CallFunction
    |  LEFTPAREN expr RIGHTPAREN                         #Parens
    |  expr POW<assoc=right> expr                        #Pow
    |  expr op=(MULTIPLY | DIVIDE) expr                  #MultDivide
    |  expr op=(ADD | SUBTRACT) expr                     #AddSubtract
    |  SUBTRACT expr                                     #Negative
    |  NUMBER                                            #Number
    ;
```

I was wondering why putting the ? breaks the matching order? And is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: This may have been fixed in the latest release. Do you have a self-contained example that demonstrates the problem so that I can test it?

Comment: Here is a simple combined lexer/parser grammar file, visitor implementation, and test program that exhibits the issue. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22576981/ANTLR4Test/Combined1.zip

Comment: I was using the Antlr4 version 4.1.0-alpha003 from Nuget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"expr expr" doesn't fit the pattern of operators though ANTLR 4.2 might handle this. Sam is still working on updating C# target.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. :) Btw, in the first grammar, implicit multiplication was working fine, it just screwed up the precedence ordering in unrelated expressions like the ones I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Split your expr statement into multiple statements in order to get proper order of operations.

Typically it goes like below:
Note how each expr only handles one set of mathematical operations and then calls down to a lower precedence rule.  Typically the lowest rule is your atomic operator like `INT` or `FLOAT`

So in this case you handle logical AND and OR's then comparisons, then exponents, then multiplications/division then addition/subtraction.

**NOTE** I should also point out, here I've created an AST tree instead of doing the operations inline.

```
expr
: subExpr -> ^(EXPR subExpr)
;

subExpr : logicalAndExp (addSubtractOp^ logicalAndExp)*
;   

logicalAndExp
: logicalOrExp (multiplyDivideOp^  logicalOrExp)*    
;

logicalOrExp
: comparatorExp (CARET^  comparatorExp)*    
;

comparatorExp
: powExp (comparatorOp^  powExp)*   
;

powExp  : multExp (BARBAR^   multExp)*  
;

multExp 
:  expressionAtom (AMPAMP^ expressionAtom)*
;expression 
: subExpr -> ^(EXPR subExpr)
;

subExpr : logicalAndExp (addSubtractOp^ logicalAndExp)*
;   

logicalAndExp
: logicalOrExp (multiplyDivideOp^  logicalOrExp)*    
;

logicalOrExp
: comparatorExp (CARET^  comparatorExp)*    
;

comparatorExp
: powExp (comparatorOp^  powExp)*   
;

powExp  : multExp (BARBAR^   multExp)*  
;

multExp 
:  expressionAtom (AMPAMP^ expressionAtom)*
;
```

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? In Antlr4, I understand they added support for direct left recursion and order the operator precedence based on the order I put them in the expr rule, which works great until I attempt to add the ? to support implicit multiplication. I was wondering why I can't put this ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on how to support it using chaining of expression types though. :) It seems I will have to do it that way for now.